# Как организовать взаимодействие между приложениями на одном сервере?

Tags: node.js, golang, http

Доброй ночи, коллеги, в данный момент пишу TG бота (На "Микросервисной архитектуре"), где за самого бота отвечает приложение на Node.JS

А за взаимодействие с базой данных приложение на Golang.

В данный момент всё реализовано на HTTP протоколе.
TG Servers -> Node.JS Bot -> Golang Back end

Но само приложение выходит не особо большим и было принято решение разворачивать всё на одном сервере.

Доступ к Back end серверу есть только у приложения отвечающего за TG бота.

Сам по себе ведь HTTP не из самых быстрых, слышал про CGI, Socket'ы, но в этом я профан.

Вот тут и сам вопрос, что стоит использовать вместо HTTP, либо же взаимодействие на уровне одного сервера не вызовет критических задержек по времени?

Comment: grpc (но, скорее всего, монолит будет быстрей)

Comment: Уже сам плачу, что не писал монолит, но практики с Go очень не хватает, поэтому так уж пришлось, а переписывать всё на ноду очень уж не хочу) Спасибо за помощь, буду смотреть!